# An inequality obtained in a minimum point

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, maxima-minima, mean-curvature-flows

I'm trying understand the article "[The Heat Equation Shrinking Convex Planes](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214439902)" by Gage and Hamilton and I'm get stuck in the proof of Theorem $3.2.1$, specifically, in the proof of this inequality:

> $\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1^2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_2^2} - \left( \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1s_2} \right)^2 \geq 0,$
>
> $\textbf{EDIT:}$
>
> where the left expression on this inequality is evaluated in a minimum point of $g$, $g$ is defined by $g(u_1,u_2,t) = f(u_1,u_2,t) + \varepsilon t$, $f$ is defined by $f: S^1 \times S^1 \times [0,T) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ($S^1$ is interpreted by the authors like $\mathbb{R}/\mod 2 \pi$), $f(u_1,u_2,t) := |F(u_1, t) - F(u_2,t)|^2$ and $F$ is a parametrization of a closed convex regular curve which trace is contained in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
>
> The parameters $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the parameters by arc length with respect the curve $F$ in the instante $t$ in the points $F(u_1,t)$ and $F(u_2,t)$ respectively.

It is stated that an easy calculation verifies this inequality, but I can't see why this inequality it's true. I know that $\frac{\partial }{\partial s} = \frac{1}{v} \frac{\partial }{\partial u}$ $\left(v = ||\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}|| \right)$. Adopting the following notation to simplify the computations, $v_1 = ||\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_1}||$ and $v_2 = ||\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_2}||$, I found

$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial s_1^2} = \frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial }{\partial u_1} \left( \frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_1} \right) = \frac{1}{v_1} \left[ \left( - \frac{1}{v_1^2} \right) \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial u_1} \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_1} + \frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1^2} \right] = \frac{1}{v_1} \left[ \left( - \frac{1}{v_1^2} \right) \langle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1^2},\frac{\partial f }{\partial u_1} \rangle \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_1} + \frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1^2} \right]$

$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_2^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial s_2^2} = \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial }{\partial u_2} \left( \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} \right) = \frac{1}{v_2} \left[ \left( - \frac{1}{v_2^2} \right) \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial u_2} \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} + \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_2^2} \right] = \frac{1}{v_2} \left[ \left( - \frac{1}{v_2^2} \right) \langle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_2^2}, \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} \rangle \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} + \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_2^2} \right]$

$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1s_2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial s_1s_2} = 
\frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial }{\partial u_1} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial s_2} \right) = \frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial }{\partial u_1} \left( 
\frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_2} \right) = \frac{1}{v_1} \left[ \left( - \frac{1}{v_2^2} \right) \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial u_1} \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} + \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1 u_2} \right] = \frac{1}{v_1} \left[ \left( - \frac{1}{v_2^2} \right) \langle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1 u_2}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_2} \rangle \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} + \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1 u_2} \right]$

Computing $\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1^2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_2^2} - \left( \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1s_2} \right)^2$, I obtained something plus the Hessian of $f$, I tried compute $\langle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1^2},\frac{\partial f }{\partial u_1} \rangle$, $\langle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_2^2},\frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} \rangle$ and $\langle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1 u_2},\frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} \rangle$, I tried study the signs of $\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial u_1}$, $\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial u_2}$ and $\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial u_1}$ in order to express $\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1^2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_2^2} - \left( \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1s_2} \right)^2$ in terms of the Hessian of $f$, because I know that in a minimum point $\det Hess \  f \geq 0$ and I would obtain the inequality desired, but I didnt have success with my attempts. Can anyone help me why this inequality its true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you included some relevant information to make your question self-contained: what are $s_1, s_2, u, v$ and how are they related? Just looking at your question it looks like you're starting with the determinant of the Hessian in the coordinates $s_1,s_2;$ so there should be no calculation necessary at all. What am I missing?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, sorry for don't put all details. I edit the topic and add some details about $g$. I put the link for the article too if you need more details.

Comment: @George I have nothing to contribute to this question, but I think it's interesting and it deserves more attention. Maybe this question will be better received in the Physics StackExchange site. You can either cross post or migrate it over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized now that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_i} = 0$ for $i = 1,2$ because the derivatives is computed in a minimum point of $g$ (and consequently of $f$), then we have that

$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial s_1^2} = \frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial }{\partial u_1} \left( \frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_1} \right) = \frac{1}{v_1} \left[ \left( - \frac{1}{v_1^2} \right) \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial u_1} \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_1} + \frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1^2} \right] = \frac{1}{v_1} \left[ \frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1^2} \right]$

$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_2^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial s_2^2} = \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial }{\partial u_2} \left( \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} \right) = \frac{1}{v_2} \left[ \left( - \frac{1}{v_2^2} \right) \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial u_2} \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} + \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_2^2} \right] = \frac{1}{v_2} \left[ \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_2^2} \right]$

$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1s_2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial s_1s_2} = 
\frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial }{\partial u_1} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial s_2} \right) = \frac{1}{v_1} \frac{\partial }{\partial u_1} \left( 
\frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_2} \right) = \frac{1}{v_1} \left[ \left( - \frac{1}{v_2^2} \right) \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial u_1} \frac{\partial f }{\partial u_2} + \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1 u_2} \right] = \frac{1}{v_1} \left[ \frac{1}{v_2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1 u_2} \right]$

Finally, we have the inequality desired

$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1^2} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_2^2} - \left( \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial s_1s_2} \right)^2 = \left( \left( \frac{1}{v_1} \right)^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1^2} \right) \left( \left( \frac{1}{v_2} \right)^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_2^2} \right) - \left( \frac{1}{v_1 v_2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1 u_2} \right)^2 = \left( \frac{1}{v_1 v_2} \right)^2 \left[ \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1^2} \right) \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_2^2} \right) - \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u_1 u_2} \right)^2  \right] = \left( \frac{1}{v_1 v_2} \right)^2 \text{Hess} \ f \geq 0$

because the Hessian of $f$ is non-negative in a minimum point.